# some issues with downsized images and their increased file sizes in c#

Tags: c#, image, resize

I have a class which helps me out to re-size my images to a specified image size but the problem is with the file sizes of the output images—actually it's kinda funny but here is the thing:

the original image is : 800x600 24bit 96dpi file-size : 82kb

the re-size image is : 466x340 24bit 96dpi file-size : 366kb

what should I do? is there any 3rd party component or open source project according to this issue?

here is my mentioned class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;


public class imageClass
{
    public enum Dimensions
    {
        Width,
        Height
    }
    public enum AnchorPosition
    {
        Top,
        Center,
        Bottom,
        Left,
        Right
    }

    public static Image ScaleByPercent(Image imgPhoto, int Percent)
    {
        float nPercent = ((float)Percent / 100);

        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;

        int destX = 0;
        int destY = 0;
        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
            new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }
    public static Image ConstrainProportions(Image imgPhoto, int Size, Dimensions Dimension)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        int destX = 0;
        int destY = 0;
        float nPercent = 0;

        switch (Dimension)
        {
            case Dimensions.Width:
                nPercent = ((float)Size / (float)sourceWidth);
                break;
            default:
                nPercent = ((float)Size / (float)sourceHeight);
                break;
        }

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
        new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
        new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }

    public static Image FixedSize(Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        int destX = 0;
        int destY = 0;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        //if we have to pad the height pad both the top and the bottom
        //with the difference between the scaled height and the desired height
        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        {
            nPercent = nPercentH;
            destX = (int)((Width - (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            nPercent = nPercentW;
            destY = (int)((Height - (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
        }

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.Clear(Color.Red);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
            new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }

    public static Image Crop(Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height, AnchorPosition Anchor)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        int destX = 0;
        int destY = 0;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        {
            nPercent = nPercentW;
            switch (Anchor)
            {
                case AnchorPosition.Top:
                    destY = 0;
                    break;
                case AnchorPosition.Bottom:
                    destY = (int)(Height - (sourceHeight * nPercent));
                    break;
                default:
                    destY = (int)((Height - (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nPercent = nPercentH;
            switch (Anchor)
            {
                case AnchorPosition.Left:
                    destX = 0;
                    break;
                case AnchorPosition.Right:
                    destX = (int)(Width - (sourceWidth * nPercent));
                    break;
                default:
                    destX = (int)((Width - (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
                    break;
            }
        }

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
            new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }

}
```

regards.

the file format I'm using is : JPEG

Comment: What file format are the images, and what code are you using?

Comment: If the original image is using some sort of compression scheme (as often is the case with JPG or PNG) and you have not defined any for the resized image, this is very possible. We need to see the code and know the image types.

Comment: Use `Image.GetThumbnailImage` and store it in a format with compression enabled.

Comment: NO, NO, NOOOOOO. Never, ever use Image.GetThumbnailImage!  Horrible quality when embedded thumbnails are present. Go read [the 28 image resizing pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/), then come back....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal side-effect of resampling the image with the InterpolationMode set to a high quality value, like Bicubic.  This subtly alters the pixel values of just about every pixel, especially since jpeg *decompression* produces subtle noise in the image.  Barely visible to the human eye, quite visible to the resampling filter.  Giving the jpeg encoder a *much* harder time compressing the image.  Only starting out with a non-compressed image format, like PNG, can improve the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not explicitly defining an image format, it will default to BMP or PNG format. If you do explicitly specify ImageFomat.Jpeg, it will use quality=100, instead of quality=90 (the best setting, with no discernable differences). [Check out the 28 image resizing pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) if you aren't going to [use the recommended library for this situation](http://imageresizing.net)

**The [ImageResizer library](http://imageresizing.net)**

You mentioned a library, and yes, it exists. The [ImageResizer library](http://imageresizing.net) avoids all of the GDI bugs, defaults to quality=90, and doesn't leak memory or GDI handles, even when images are corrupted. It also supports autocropping, manual cropping, resizing, rotating, and a ton of other features. It's time tested, traffic tested, and unit tested.

It has a 1-line API that is very simple to use. 
[Go check it out!](http://imageresizing.net)